# How to Create and Remove HTML elements with Javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

How to Create and Remove HTML elements with Java script dynamically..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `appendChild` and `removeChild`, respectively

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild

you could also use

- [innerHTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20120305003651/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.innerHTML) to append/remove elements ([in some circustances](http://jsperf.com/fragment-vs-appendchild-vs-innerhtml/6) can be more suitable, especially for large node insertion)
- [createDocumentFragment](https://web.archive.org/web/20120521042046/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) really useful for appending DOM structures with sub-nested elements

Comment: Thanks for the link provided.

Comment: Downvoter cares to explain his downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You can user jQuery for use the HTML DOM easier

```
.remove();
.append('</div>');
```

All the documentations is here : http://api.jquery.com/